# Autofill Runtime error 1004 - autofill dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to autofill (xlFillFormats) a dynamic range according to a user input.

The code is:

```
    If iInputRows > 1 Then
    Rows(14).Resize(iInputRows, Columns.Count).EntireRow.Insert _
      Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("D13").Resize(iInputRows, 1).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, _
      Type:=xlLinear, Step:=1
    Range("X13:AR13").Resize(iInputRows, 21).FillDown
    Rows(13 + iInputRows).Delete
    Range("O13:U13").Resize(iInputRows, 7).AutoFill Destination:=Range("O13:U" & iInputRows), Type:=xlFillFormats

End If
```

Technically, all the rows that have been inserted should have the same formats as their corresponding sources cells.  However, the particular range O:U (with number of rows decided by user input) is deciding to exclude the cell formatting.
I am having difficulty correcting for this in line 8 of the code above, to which I get a Runtime error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error lies here

```
Destination:=Range("O13:U" & iInputRows)
```

You forgot to offset the rows of the destination range, it should be like this:

```
Destination:=Range("O13:U" & 13 + iInputRows)
```

EDIT:

also, `.Resize(iInputRows, 7)` is unnecessary if you wish to copy the formatting of the first row only and should be removed.

Comment: Thanks Marek.  A good suggestion.  Unfortunately, I am not getting the response that I want (the cell borders are still not getting filled in the correct format).  If I input your code above, the cell borders do not get copied and I get one extra row than required.  So I modified the code to 'Destination:=Range("O13:U" & 13 + iInputRows - 1)' to which I get the runtime error again.  I think I may just have to automate the border settings rather than autofill.

Comment: what formatting do you wish to copy? Just the first row, the O13:U13? If so, you do not need to Resize statement on that line.

Comment: Yeah, just first row.  That has done it.  Thanks Marek.